# Find out which TableView has been tapped

Tags: uitableview, swift, uigesturerecognizer

My `ViewController` has multiple `UITableViews` and I added a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` for the cells. Whenever the gesture has been called, I want to show up a popover. When I had just one TableView I could just use:

```
if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(recognizer.locationInView(tableView)) {
    // code
}
```

Now I have multiple `TableViews` I don't know how to tell the method which `TableView` it should be using to find the `indexPath`.

Should I use custom `GestureRecognizers` just as identifiers? It doesn't seem a real good solution as I have to make a new `GestureRecognizer` for every `TableView` I have in this `ViewController`.

Can someone tell me an easy solution for this?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, are you absolutely sure that you need multiple table views on a single view controller? Sounds like a pretty bad design flaw.

Comment: Yea, I have two tables because one of the table shows a few rows which I don't want to scroll along with the main tableview. Why is it bad design if I may ask?

Comment: To keep things simple and in order. If you complicate your design, things would go awry easily as you are experiencing. To answer you question; I would separate the tables' data source and delegate from each other for easy handling. But if it is just a few rows of data I would just use labels for non scrolling parts.

Comment: I agree with @Desdenova. Don't use multiple tableviews if you can do it with a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Assign a different tag to each table view.. Check the tag first before doing any operation...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your multiple tables are all subviews of view A and don't overlap:

- Get the gesture's location in view A
- Check if each table view's `frame` contains the location

As soon as you find one that does, that's the touched table.

Alternatively you can get the gesture's location in each table view in turn, and check if it is within the `bounds`.